# Importing very big dataset into Neo4j

Tags: csv, import, neo4j, bigdata

I have a huge csv data set of ca. 7GB, which has columns of different types: string and float. So what is the super fast solution for importing it into Neo4j?

I tried also using neo4j-admin import tool, but every time I got stuck by following error:

Invoke-Neo4jAdmin :
C:\Users\Shafigh.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-417e361b-f273-496c-9836-4fca6f80d0c0\installation-3.4.1 is not
a valid Neo4j installation.  Missing
C:\Users\Shafigh.Neo4jDesktop\neo4jDatabases\database-417e361b-f273-496c-9836-4fca6f80d0c0\installation-3.4.1\lib
At line:1 char:161
+ ... sd1'; Exit (Invoke-Neo4jAdmin import --nodes import/similarity_pairs_ ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-Neo4jAdmin

Answer (score 0):

[The Import section](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/import/) of the neo4j Operations Manual describes how to use the `import` command of the `neo4j-admin` tool "do batch imports of large amounts of data" into a new neo4j database.

The `import` command is extremely fast because it directly builds the internal files of the new database and does not have to deal with transactions.

Comment: Looks like you need to reinstall neo4j.

Comment: Ok, I will do it. And could you know, how the internal file look like? my file has csv format including headers, so does internal file look like table with headers as column ? or it has another structure?

Comment: The neo4j internal files are not CSV files.

Comment: i know it, so my question is, what structure they have?

Comment: You can check the [open source neo4j code](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j) to see how they structure their variuous internal files. But I would not expect the structure to stay unchanged between neo4j versions.